# python trying to match 1 list partially with an other list

Tags: python

I've got 2 list with data in it and I want to match the first list with the second one.

in my second list the data contain's the first list and some other data as one object.

the lists

```
list_1 = [
    'id1',
    'id2'
]

list_2 = [
    'a815-8d4a  -- id5',
    'aba2-a6ac  -- id5',
    'e7f0-efbf  -- id1'
]
```

the output I'm looking for is that there is a new list created or that `list_2` is filtered to look like this

```
x = ['e7f0-efbf']
```

I have tried to use any with for loops like below but it only matches the full id in 2nd list.

```
q = [i for i in list_1 if any(i for j in list_2 if str(j) in i)]
print(q)
```

Comment: So from list_2 you want to filter the elements that end with some element from list_1? And strip of the the end of the string?

Comment: Do you want to match strings from list_1 **anywhere** in strings from list_2? It looks like the first token in the list_2 strings are hexadecimal numbers in which case searching e.g., for 'id1' would be unambiguous. But what if the values in list_1 were values that could be hexadecimal sequences - e.g., ab1

Comment: Alternative: `print([v for v, key in (x.split('  -- ') for x in list_2) if key in list_1])`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you had switched around `list_1` and `list_2` you would have

```
>>> [i for i in list_2 if any(i for j in list_1 if str(j) in i)]
['e7f0-efbf  -- id1']
```

And now this goes through the items in `list_2` and only grabs the ones that has an id from `list_1` in them.

But this isn't that readable, and as Olvin Roght pointed out, it could cause problems as it is checking for an id in the entirety of each list_2 item, and I assume you only want to check for an id in the latter part. The way I would solve this problem is like this

```
res = []
for id2_id1 in list_2:
    id2, id1 = id2_id1.split('  -- ')
    if id1 in list_1:
        res.append(id2)
print(res) 
# prints ['e7f0-efbf']
```

Comment: I feel a bit stupid right now. Thanks works. I can use regex to clean the list up

Comment: This will match the 'key' from list_1 wherever it exists in a list_2 element whereas the data format seems to suggest (to me anyway) that it should only match the last token in a list_2 string. Also, what is the significance of *str(j)* in your code? Isn't *j* already a string?

Comment: @Olvin Roght My answer now takes care of the concerns you brought up

Answer (score 1):

This code might work, assuming you search for the code associated with each id in the second list(if my interpretation is wrong please correct me):

```
list_1 = [
    'id1',
    'id2'
]

list_2 = [
    'a815-8d4a  -- id5',
    'aba2-a6ac  -- id5',
    'e7f0-efbf  -- id1'
]
x = []
for i in list_1:
    for j in list_2:
        if j.find(i)>-1:
            x.append(j[:j.find(i)-5])
            
print(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's make an assumption here - i.e., that the strings in list_2 each contain at least two whitespace delimited tokens and that each token is of indeterminate length.

Therefore we can use a list comprehension as follows:

```
result = [v for v, *_, k in map(str.split, list_2) if k in list_1]
print(result)
```

...which gives us...

```
['e7f0-efbf']
```